# Installing Jupyter Labs - Can't get it to work

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

All:

Hope you all could provide some assistance here. I am new to all of this and getting into data science / analytics. I hear Jupyter Labs is a great IDE to use. However, when I install it here is the command I use and and the results I get:

[Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXzry.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6A1g.png)

However, once i try to run the jupyter-lab command this is the message from the Command Prompt:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugjbV.png)

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a path configuration issue. As a quick check, what do the commands: `jupyter lab`, `python -m jupyterlab`, `python3 -m jupyterlab`, `jupyter --path` result in?

Comment: jupyterlab: C:\Users\17027>jupyter lab 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

python -m jupyterlab: this actually loaded it, thanks!